# Field auto update

Tags: database, ms-access, ms-access-2010

As a nearly computer illiterate cow farmer I have built a database based around the details of the individual cows I have on my farm.

I have a field in my my main table which records the current location of a given animal at any one time.

I have now created a form with a command button which runs a SearchForRecord macro to bring up the details of an individual animal. I am trying to get it to automatically update the location field to a pre-set value from an unbound textbox when it finds a matching record. Can anyone help me?

Comment: What type of database?  Can you post the macro code you have so far? You need to give more details on your environment, and what you've tried so far.

Comment: Same thing crossed my mind. ;)

Comment: Sorry, yes this is MS Access 2010

Comment: The searchfor criteria is: ="[EID Tag] = '" & [Forms]![frm Weight gain]![SearchEID] & "'"

Answer (score 0):

I would think EID would be a number, therefore you wouldn't need the single quotes since they are for used for strings.  So it should be:

```vb
="[EID Tag] = " & [Forms]![frm Weight gain]![SearchEID]
```

Also I must say for a nearly computer illiterate farmer, I'm impressed.

Answer (score 0):

A little bit too long for a comment.

You can probably do what you want using the [RunSQL Macro Action](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff192476(v=office.14).aspx) to execute an update statement. There is a pretty good example of an update query in the corresponding [DomCmd.RunSQL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194626.aspx) subroutine. You would need to parameterise the query much like you have with the where condition.

There seems to be a question regarding this action [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25226574/using-select-top-with-a-passing-variant-in-runsql-action-of-a-macro-giving-me-er) which should also help.